# Is it possible decompress a zip file while maintaining hierarchy using just .NET or some other built-in Windows API?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, zip

I have a zip file that contains folder hierarchies and files.

```
\images\
\images\1.jpg
\images\2.jpg
\something\something\a.exe
\something\something\b.exe
1.txt
```

I need to decompress the contents of this zip file to a location. I also need to preserve the structure of the zip file.

I've read about .NET's [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28VS.80%29.aspx) but I am of the opinion that it is too "complicated" for my purpose.

I've also used DotNetZip and SharpZipLib in the past for personal projects but since this is work related and I'm working at a huge company, I would have a hard time convincing legal to use these libraries.

Question:
Is it possible decompress a zip file while maintaining hierarchy using just .NET or some other built-in Windows API?

PS: I've also read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/decompresswinshellapics.aspx) but I think it's hacky because you'll need to produce another executable just to hide the progress dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note - both DotNetZip and SharpZipLib have a permissive license (MS-PL and LGPL, respectively) - it means that you can use the library (in binary format without modifications) in commercial projects without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out if [Ionic Zip](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/c1d9ee47-6e35-bcbe-3d5d-f9379d9e7dcc.htm)  helps?

Comment: Ionic Zip is part of DotNetZip, an open source project. As mentioned, the Legal team would need to take a look at this which will take a LOT of time.

Comment: Send them some money, I'm sure they'd give you a license.

Comment: The licensing terms says that redistribution is allowed. So it should be easy unless you want to modify DotNetZip source...Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) is pretty lenient that way.

Comment: `it should be easy unless you want to modify DotNetZip source...`  No need to qualify your statement. Under Ms-PL, you *can* modify the source, and even redistribute if you wish. To wit:  *...grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright license to reproduce its contribution, prepare derivative works of its contribution, and distribute its contribution or any derivative works that you create.*  http://opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html

Comment: Yeah, I figured that using a matured, well-tested zip framework is the best way to go. I've already notified Legal about it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

DotNetZip would do what you want, but I understand your concerns about legal approval.

On a side note, It might be good for you to navigate the legal jungle associated with getting an open-source library approved for use in the company, just to understand what's involved.  But I'll leave that up to you.

---

Getting back to rolling your own... 
DotNetZip is pretty full featured, and it handles a number of scenarios you probably don't care about.  Like Unicode filenames and comments, setting windows timestamps and permissions of extracted files, getting timestamps of zip files created on old unix systems, split archives, Encrypted archives, files over 2gb, or self-extracting archives, etc etc etc. Many zip files use none of those things.

Also DotNetZip does eventing and zip updates and zip creation - all the code associated with these things is probably not of interest to you, if you confine yourself just to the requirements you described in your question.

You could, though, grab the DotNetZip code and use it to help you roll your own solution. If you constrain yourself to JUST reading zip files and not dealing with all the possible special cases, the zip format is not difficult to parse.

here's how to do it:

1. open the zip file using `new FileStream()` or `File.Open`. You want a `FileStream` object.
2. Read 4 bytes. Verify that it is the zip-entry-header descriptor. (0x04034b50)
   In the file, the order you will find these bytes is 50 4b 03 04.
3. if you find a match, you're in business.

   - at offset 14 is a 4-byte CRC.  Get it. (Same byte ordering as above)
   - at offset 18 - the 4-byte length of the compressed blob. get it.  (N)
   - at offset 22 - the 4-byte length of the UNcompressed blob. get it.  (U)
   - at 26 - the 2-byte length of the filename. get it  (L)
   - at 28 - the 2-byte length of the "extra field". get it (E)
4. Beyond the extra field, at offset 30, is the actual filename. read L bytes for the filename, and call System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(). The result will include a directory path, with the backslashes replaced with slashes (unix style). String.Replace() the slashes.
5. after the filename comes the extra field - seek E bytes to get beyond it. You can mostly ifgnore it. This is where the compressed data starts.
6. Open a System.IO.DeflateStream() on the zip FileStream, using CompressionMode.Decompress, and using the current offset of the FileStream as input. open a new FileStream, for output, with the file path you read in step 3. in a loop, call inflater.Read(). and output.Write(), to write the decompressed output of the DeflateStream to a filesystem file with the correct name. You will need to stop reading from the DeflateStream when you read exactly U (uncompressed) bytes.
7. Check the uncompressed size (U) against the data you actually wrote out from the DeflateStream (after compression). They should match.
8. If you are fancy, you can check the CRC of the output against what was in the header.
9. go to step 2, to look for the next entry in the file.

The most complicated part is step 3. Working code for that is easily found in [this source module](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65587#679992), look for the ReadHeader method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the full features set of GZipStream it's a bit complicated, but note that the sample in the msdn page it's exactly what you need. I mean this msdn web (the 4.0 version) not the one you supply in the question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx#Y2750

Comment: Thanks! The example assumed that the zip package only contains one file, not multiple files.

Comment: Contrary to perceptions, GZipStream cannot read zip files.  It says this right in the doc page: `this class does not inherently provide functionality for adding files to or extracting files from .zip archives.`  Also, the example you cited compresses N files into N .gz files, which is not what the OP asked about.